# Show preloader before Google Maps is ready - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

How can I check if Google Maps is ready or not? I want to show preloader block when Google maps is loading.

I have the factory:

```
var map = false;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.6908333333, 9.14055555556);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    minZoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    draggableCursor:'crosshair',
    zoomControl: false,
        center: myLatlng,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
    preserveViewport: true
}

function addMap(mapId) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}
function getMap(mapId) {
    if (!map) addMap(mapId);
        return map;
}

return {
    addMap: addMap,
    getMap: getMap
}
```

And inside controller:

```
$scope.map = GoogleMaps.getMap();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set an event listener on Google maps to be fired once the map is ready:

```
function addMap(mapId) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function () {
        scope.$emit('mapInitialized', map);
    });
}
```

And then inside your splash screen directive you listen for the event

```
$scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
    // in here you set some variable to actually hide the splash screen
});
```

Sample code with a black splash screen:

```js
angular
  .module('splashMap', [])
  .directive('map', function() {
      var link = function(scope, element) {

        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.style.width = "100%";
        el.style.height = "100%";
        element.prepend(el);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
          center: {
            lat: 48.6908333333,
            lng: 9.14055555556
          },
          zoom: 8

        });

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
          scope.$emit('mapInitialized', map);
        });

      }
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
      };

    }

  ).directive('splash', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element) {
      scope.loaded = false;
      scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(e, map) {
        console.log('loaded');
        scope.loaded = true;
        scope.$apply();
      })
    }
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: link,
    }
  });
```

```css
body,
html,
map {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
map,
splash {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
splash {
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="splashMap">

  <splash ng-hide="loaded"></splash>

  <map></map>

</body>
```

Comment: @caio-iglesias This solution works great :) thanks. But I have a question: do you know Why for viewing google maps via a directive we have to create a new `div` and insert it? why is `element` not ready enough at the time of `link`?

Answer (score 0):

I personaly have not used google maps jet.

But couldnt you do it by using this event

```
tilesloaded
```

Or one of the othe events reference in this document

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference
```